# How do you convert PSF music files to FLAC without using some "online tool"?

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, conversion, flac

I love the soundtrack to the 1997 PlayStation video game *Breath of Fire III*.

I have its soundtrack as MP3 files on my computer.

After hearing what a huge difference it made to go from MP3 to FLAC for the soundtrack to *Final Fantasy VII*, I wish to do the same for *BoF III*.

Unfortunately, there is no FLAC (meaning lossless) release available.

However, there is a "PSF" version to download: https://www.zophar.net/music/playstation-psf/breath-of-fire-iii

PSF is a strange and seemingly "legacy" (unsupported/dead) music format which is not supported by **FFMPEG**, which was my first go-to tool for trying to convert it to FLAC.

Online, I find many webpages which appear to allow me to convert a PSF file to FLAC, but I'm not interested in sitting there and doing it manually for every track. I just want the tool to do it myself. Also, I can't be sure what kind of special/wrong settings they might be using.

I would like to do something like:

```
convert.exe -i "test.psf" -o "test.flac"
```

Please tell me I'm not stuck with my 320 kb/s MP3s?

PS: Before anyone suggests it, I found one weird Russian site which *claims* to have it as FLAC, but locked beyond a registration form, and when I tried to register, the site automatically IP-banned me. If they have it, it's inaccessible to me.

Comment: [Breath of Fire III (Remastered Tracks) | Sean Schafianski](https://seanschafianski.bandcamp.com/album/breath-of-fire-iii-remastered-tracks) has flac format ($10)

Comment: Also on Steam [Breath of Fire III Sound Collection on Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1335090/Breath_of_Fire_III_Sound_Collection/)

Comment: "huge difference it made to go from MP3 to FLAC" was this a conversion, one to the other, or did you just source from elsewhere? http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=PSF

Comment: @Tetsujin I mean source from elsewhere. To replace my old MP3s.

Comment: The source conversion was probably better for the flac. Most people have difficulty telling the difference on a blind test from the same source.

Answer (score 1):

The [Video Game Music Preservation Foundation](http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) has a page on [PSF](http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=PSF) which lists a few players:

> Audio Overload - Linux, Macintosh, Windows (Horribly Buggy)
> Highly Experimental - Winamp, XMPlay (32-bit only in 2020)
> PSF Decoder - foobar2000 (32-bit only in 2020)
> UPSE PSF Decoder [1] - foobar2000 (32-bit only in 2020)
> AOPSF Decoder [2] - foobar2000 (32-bit only in 2020)

[Audio Overload](https://www.bannister.org/software/ao.htm) for example lists "Export-to-WAV functionality" in its features.

Once you have a WAV file, you can convert this to FLAC or any other format you desire.

Comment: Well, I tried that software. It does support it, but in an extremely clunky and manual manner... It will be a nightmare to do this one by one...

Comment: Update: Actually doesn't seem to be working at all. Doesn't save the files or give any error...

Comment: Too bad, how do the other suggestions work? There are a few foobar and winamp plugins, my guess is you can export to WAV from those applications. By the way, if an application has no API and can only be used via the GUI, you can try "automating" it using an autoclicker like tinytask or mouserecorder pro.